# SQL Developer - Third Party JDBC Driver Silent Configuration

Tags: java, powershell, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am in the process of getting a third-party JDBC driver (Snowflake) configured in SQL Dev, but running into issues. I am unsure how to get paths set in Preferences > Database > Third Party JDBC Drivers. I noticed on a few posts that this is related to the CLASSPATH env variable, but this didn't seem to work (the field was blank in the related window, attempting to load from the Connections tab gave the error: Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver).

I created the new connection by modifying the connections.json script in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Romaing\SQL Developer\system*version*\o.jdeveloper.db.connection directory. This works, as it to populates in the connections tab after completion. Currently this script is in PowerShell, apologies I do not know Oracle applications well:

```
$TestPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('CLASSPATH', 'Machine')
If ($TestPath.Contains('C:\Oracle\sqldeveloper\jdbc\jdbc-proxy.jar'))
    {
        Echo "Path Environment Variable already set. Skipping creation."
    }
else
    {
        $path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('CLASSPATH', 'Machine')
        $newpath = $path + ';C:\Oracle\sqldeveloper\jdbc\jdbc-proxy.jar'
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("CLASSPATH", $newpath, 'Machine')

    }
If ($TestPath.Contains('C:\Oracle\sqldeveloper\jdbc\snowflake-jdbc.jar'))
    {
        Echo "Path Environment Variable already set. Skipping creation."
    }
else
    {
        $path2 = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('CLASSPATH', 'Machine')
        $newpath2 = $path2 + ';C:\Oracle\sqldeveloper\jdbc\snowflake-jdbc.jar'
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("CLASSPATH", $newpath2, 'Machine')

    }
```

Here is a link to the process I am attempting to accomplish (different driver): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-a-jdbc-driver-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to succeed here. SQL Developer only allows specific 3rd party JDBC drivers, and Snowflake isn't one of them.

Sybase ASE, SQL Server, Teradata, DB2 LUW, AWS Redshift, and MySQL are all allowed. We're working on PostgreSQL for formal migration support, the driver/connections should work already.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Just curious, for the allowed drivers (lets say MySQL), is this direction to go if wanting to configure it in SQL Developer or am I completely off?